# Output Data from DataAdapter to HTML Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The following code seems to generate a DataAdapter:

```
protected void grdMain_Databind()
{
    DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
    using (IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection())
    {
        string sSQL;
        sSQL = "select * , " + ControlChars.CrLf
           + " CASE isnull((select TOP 1 EMAIL_ID from EMAILS_ATTACHMENTS WHERE ATTACHMENT_ID=vwFILES_ATTACHMENTS.ATTACHMENT_ID),'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') " + ControlChars.CrLf
           + "    WHEN  '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'      THEN '0'  ELSE '1' END AS  SENT_ATTACHMENT  " + ControlChars.CrLf
           + "     , case File_ext when '.pdf' then 'true' else 'false' end as 'enablecheck'" + ControlChars.CrLf
           + "     , case VISIBLE_TO_CLIENT when '1' then '" + Session["themeURL"].ToString() + "images/check_inline.gif'" + ControlChars.CrLf
           + "                              else '" + Session["themeURL"].ToString() + "images/close_inline.gif' " + ControlChars.CrLf
           + "                              end as 'VISIBLE_TO_CLIENT_PATH'" + ControlChars.CrLf
           + "  from vwFILES_ATTACHMENTS" + ControlChars.CrLf
           + " where 1 = 1 " + ControlChars.CrLf;

        using (IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                using (DbDataAdapter da = dbf.CreateDataAdapter())
                {
                    ((IDbDataAdapter)da).SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        vwMain = dt.DefaultView;
                        grdMain.DataSource = vwMain;
                        // 09/05/2005 Paul. LinkButton controls will not fire an event unless the the grid is bound. 
                        if (!IsPostBack)
                        {
                            //grdMain.SortColumn = "DATE_ENTERED";
                            //grdMain.SortOrder = "desc";
                            //grdMain.ApplySort();
                        }
                        grdMain.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SplendidError.SystemError(new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0), ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I output that data into an HTML table?  I have tried the following but I get an error that says `'dt' does not exist in the current context`:

```
<% foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) { %> <!-- loop through the list -->
    <div>
        <%= row.ID %> <!-- write out the name of the site -->
    </div>
<% } %> <!--End the for loop -->
```

Comment: It looks like "dt" is only defined in your databind event and isn't scoped to be seen in your foreach loop.

Comment: How can I adjust the code behind to make it scope properly, do you think?

Comment: You could set a public property/field on the code behind, but you'll need to drop the `using` construct.

Comment: So, I must be calling the wrong method, it says, "The type or namespace name 'DataRow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" when I try to call `DataRow row`.

Comment: probably missing a namespace "using" -- foreach(System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows) should do it (or add <% using System.Data %> in the declarations.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that but now it says, "System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found."  How do you think I can debug this type of issue?

Comment: @user1477388 you should be using [<asp:Repeater>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) or [<asp:GridView>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) and binding them to your results... not looping. You'll have *much* more flexibility that way.